# Проблемы со стартом

Tags: c#, linux, unity3d, linux-mint

Установил Unity на Linux Mint, вроде стало, но при работе однаруживаются проблемы.

1. Не запускается редактор по клику на иконке файла C#, хотя в настройках проставлен "MonoDevelop". - Как запустить?
2. Сообщение об ошибке: 
   "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" - хотя файл только что создал, и код нулячий.
3. "TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD, underlying allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD has unfreed allocations" - при попытке вызвать редактор программирования в СиШарп.
4. "Couldn't open /opt/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/VR/Android/AudioPluginOculusSpatializer.so, error:
   /opt/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityExtensions/Unity/VR/Android/AudioPluginOculusSpatializer.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32"

Как исправить/стартонуть?

Comment: 4. Погадаю на гуще: редактор установлен из стороннего места под 32-битную платформу, тогда как у вас только 64-битная без multilib. Решение: добавить архитектуру i386, доустановить 32-битное окружение. Гуглить по ключевому слову *multilib*.

Comment: Заметил что в пропертиесах сообщается:
No supported VCS diff tools were found. Pleas one of the folowing tools:
- SourceGear DiffMerge
- TkDiff
- P4 Merge
- PlasticSCM Merge
- Beyong Compare 4
- Meld

- Это может иметь значение? Вероятно на предмет дополнительных требований по инсталляции должны быть какие-то советы - киньте ссылкой.

Comment: Я не указал ноер версии - вы об этом? Первоначально использовал 5.5.0p3, но заметил что "V5.5" - это не последняя версия, - они сменили стиль нумерации версий: теперь нумеруются в стиле "2017***". Система: i3-2120 3.3GHz 64bits c HDGraphics 2000, 4GB, Linux Mint Serena 18.1 Mate.

Я установил последнюю версию, запустил и обнаружил отсутствие вышеуказанных сообщений об ошибках, что не может не радовать, но я по прежнему не могу запустить редактор C#, что не может не огорчать. Вопрос по прежнему актуален.

Comment: Смотрите ещё новости: не запускаются ни внутренний редактор ни внешний Monodevelop, хотя он есть рядом с Unity. В пакетах Линукса он не указан, и я, предполагая что он не установлен, установил его - теперь у меня два редактора Monodevelop, с разным окружением (в новом нет текста про Unity в поле About).

Comment: Удалил новый Monodevelop, попробовал запустить - и он запустился (с пометкой про Unity). Отдельно от Unity, через файловый браузер Сажа, попробовал запустить скрипт по ассоциации и обнаружил - то редактора в списке ассоциаций нет. Нет так-же ничего похожего и в диспетчере процессов - вероятно запускается по другому. По тексту команды на иконке я узнал полный путь редактора и смог настроить ассоциацию, после чего редактор, подхватив скрипт, нормально запустился. Это говорит о том - что Unity инсталлировала вместе с собой програмный редактор (и внешний и внутренний),

Comment: но оба они не запускаются из среды Unity.

Думаю это может быть из-за не настроеных прав по файловым путям в системе, или типа того. Как это проверить?